# Prove, by definition, $\lim_{z \rightarrow 3}(\frac{z^2-3}{z+1})=\frac{3}{2}$ ($z \in \mathbb{C}$)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove, by definition, $\lim_{z \rightarrow 3}(\frac{z^2-3}{z+1})=\frac{3}{2}$ ($z \in \mathbb{C}$)

Let $\epsilon >0 $ we need to determine $\delta >0$ such that $|z-3| < \delta$
implies $|\frac{z^2-3}{z+1}-\frac{3}{2}| < \epsilon$. Thus,

$$|\frac{z^2-3}{z+1}-2|=|z-3+\frac{z-3}{2(z+1)}| \leq |z-3|+\frac{|z-3|}{2|z+1|}=|z-3|(1+\frac{1}{2|z+1|})$$

If $|z-3|<1$ then

$$|z+1|=|z-3+4| \geq |4| - |z-3| \geq 4-1=3$$ then

$$|\frac{z^2-3}{z+1}-\frac{3}{2}| \leq \frac{7}{6}|z-3|$$

$\delta=min \{1, \frac{6}{7}\epsilon\} >0 \forall \epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Isn't the limit $\dfrac{3^2-3}{3+1}=\dfrac64=\dfrac32$?

Comment: Limit is 2, sure?

Comment: I fixed it, am I right?